# How to change the timezone of my mysql TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Hi I'm really new to mysql and I am trying to do auto timestamping. However, I found that the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gave me the wrong time zone (8hr difference). I don't want to change the timezone of my machine, so I looked up and found the `DATE_ADD()` method.

I tried to use `DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INVTERVAL +8 HOUR)` in my sql script but when I execute it returns a syntax error.

This is my sql script.

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testWeatherDB;

CREATE DATABASE testWeatherDB;

use testWeatherDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL +8 HOUR) ON UPDATE DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL +8 HOUR),
        humidity DECIMAL(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
        temperature DECIMAL(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
        pressure DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
        airqualityindex DECIMAL(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
        uvindex DECIMAL(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
        particledensity DECIMAL(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
        image VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'IMG NOT FOUND',
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Is there any syntax error in my script or maybe I used `DATE_ADD()` in the wrong way?

Comment: As I read the documentation: For any TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column in a table, you can assign the current timestamp as the default value, the auto-update value, or both. I find nowhere the ability to use an arbitrary function, such as DATE_ADD.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL always stores the date and time in UTC so it can be easily converted to different timezone. NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() return the date/time plus your current timezone configured.